# Bootstrap dropdown not working --- how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have looked at other similar questions, but all of them does not work.
I'm using Django, and here's my code.

`index.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            Cleaveway Pizzas
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html`

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap-grid.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap-reboot.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'pizza/login.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'pizza/navbar.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'import/import.css' %}">
    <link rel="script" href="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}">
    <link rel="script" href="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap.js' %}">
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help? It shows the button but nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: have you added your css and js to static folder?

Comment: yes. They are in my static folder and the route is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using appropriate scripts as per bootstrap documentation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<link rel="script" href="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}">
<link rel="script" href="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap.js' %}">
```

by:

```
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I believe that is what I should have done. However, after the change the error still persists and an error message occurs:
```
bootstrap.bundle.js:120 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at setTransitionEndSupport (bootstrap.bundle.js:120)
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:223
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:9
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:10
bootstrap.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at setTransitionEndSupport (bootstrap.js:121)
    at bootstrap.js:224
    at bootstrap.js:9
    at bootstrap.js:10
```

Comment: @KeungEliot try to load bootstrap.js first and then load bootstrap.bundle.js libraries, or import the jquery library first